# Spring Tool Suite not responding suddenly

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.9.0. Till yesterday, my STS was working fine. All of a sudden, when i try to open my STS.exe, it is asking for my workspace location...once I click on "Launch" it gets closed without any error. I tried many times and even tried to remove and re-download STS 3.9.0, still no use. I don't know what is the problem. I searched in the net but nothing helps me. I am using Java 8 and Maven 3.3.9.
Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you choose a different workspace or maybe a fresh one? Does it crash, too?

Comment: Yes, I tried with a new workspace too. It didn't workout.

Comment: Hmmm... Hard to guess what is going wrong there. What happens if you open the workspace with a fresh STS 3.9.2 installation?

Comment: Actually I was not able to run my Maven project in STS 3.9.2. So only I installed STS 3.9.0. I don't know whether fresh installation solves my problem, since I tried fresh installation with STS 3.9.0 itself and still no use.

Comment: can you share a sample project that you can't use in STS 3.9.2? Would be interested in taking a look to find out what the problem might be.